# TypeScript in React application instead of ES6?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have seen React projects and examples where people have decided to use TypeScript instead of ES6. Wondering what we can not achieve using ES6, which is possible by using TypeScript with React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm sure you know, ES6 is additional features for javascript. Typescript, being a superset of javascript, also implements these features. If you want to leverage ES7 features with typescript as well, you can configure it to do so. So Typescript and ESX are independent. As Basarat said, what Typescript gives you is compile time type checking: an ability and notation for defining types in your code. To paint a picture of what it can be like to use, here is a contrived example. If you have data coming in from an api...

```
type Category = "Kitchen" | "Hardware" | "Linens";

//dont know exactly what users[n].about looks like yet
type Data = {
  users: {name: string, id: string, about: any}[];
  products: {name: string, id: string: category: Category}[];
}

export async function getUsers() {
  const data: Data = await fetch.get('localhost:3000/api');
  return data.users.map(u => u.name);
}
```

There are a number of beenefits here.

1. When writing `data.users.map`, my IDE knows users is an array and suggests array functions for me.
2. My IDE will give me a red line if i try doing a non array function on an array.
3. When I am writing this part `u => u.name`, my IDE will know the type of U, and autosuggest u.name and u.id for me
4. My IDE will give me a red line error if i try typing something else besides those two properties. I dont need to console.log it to double check for typos.

Furthermore, if I try creating a function `addProduct`, I can pull out my type definition for `Product` as well and use it again like so:

```
export function addProduct(product: Product) {
  data.products.push(product);
}
```

...if when you go to try and use that function, but dont use one of the strings defined in `Category` above, you'll get an error for this as well!

```
addProducts({name: "Missile Launcher", id: "Boom10001", Category: "Artillary"});
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed information bro, appreciate it. But all the IDE related benefits can be achieved using various plugins I guess. So, overall, I think only Types related benefits, other than that it's a personal preference of the developer.

Comment: The IDE benefits that come in via plugins are usually possible because the plugin is trying to make some kind of type inference. It's not always accurate, and if you don't explicitly tell it what you are working with / exporting from a module, it usually cannot guess. Regarding overall utility, my rule of thumb is, if im building anything of non-trivial size that will require maintenance, its almost always worth the extra hassle IMO.

Comment: Ah, and I totally missed your question about react. TS is actually really nice in React. Instead of proptypes, you use types. And you get the added benefit of in IDE error notifications, instead of run time. For example, you use typescript to say your component has props which requires a name and id, and nothing else: you will receive in IDE errors for any extra or missing props when you try using that component

Answer (score 2):

> Wondering what we can not achieve using ES6, which is possible by using TypeScript with React?

TypeSafety . TypeScript provides *compile time* type checking, something that ES6 / Pure JavaScript doesn't provide : http://www.typescriptlang.org/ / [Why TypeScript](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/why-typescript.html)

Comment: That being said, if you switch `checkJS` to true, and have a `jsconfig.json` file in VS Code, you also get Type checking and Intellisense in Javascript, and you can use `.d.ts` files. There are still some other differences between TS and JS of course.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. Yes, I was under the same impression that TypeScript gives Type Safety during compilation which can be achieved in ESX versions too. Other than that, I think there is no major benefit. Sometimes, the developer's personal preference according to skills etc...